# Application trust level

Tags: c#, winforms, permissions, oledb, trust

How can i change Trust level?
I writing c# windows form app with oledb and can't use append query because access disable mode prevent that.

Comment: Post the connect string you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the .NET Framework Configuration Tool, [to increase assembly trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

- Click the **Runtime Security Policy** node of the console tree.
- Click the **Action** menu, and select from the available commands.
- Alternately, you can right-click the **Runtime Security Policy** node and select from the same list of commands on the shortcut menu, or click the **Increase Assembly Trust** link in the pane on the right. The tool displays a corresponding wizard.
- Follow the directions that appear in the wizard to increase the level of trust granted to an assembly that you specify.
- The wizard allows you to modify security policy based upon available information about the assembly's evidence. For a list and description of the common types of evidence, see the [Evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5x1hcd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) topic.

Answer (score 4):

in Visual Studio Open your project > go to Project Menu > Properties > Security > Check Enable ClickOnce Security settings > This is a full trust application.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to also sign the ClickOnce manifests and the assembly with a Code Signing certificate for it to work in Windows 10. I didn't have to sign my deployed app in windows 7 and got away with it in windows 8 but not in 10.